# GCRectMake error in Swift 3 with specific code

Tags: swift, xcode, syntax, swift3

A quite general question. What exact syntax should I use instead of `CGRectMake` while coding in Swift 3?

Here is the code I would like to convert from swift 2 - 3:

```
{let size = text.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(view.frame.width - 26, 2000), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading.union(.UsesLineFragmentOrigin), context: nil).size}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks, I have already seen this thread. I get the same error but mu usage of CGRectMake is different, so the recommended solution does not work. I can send a screenshot of how I use CGRectMake in my code in a few hours.

Answer (score 14):

in Swift 3.0 this can be use

```
let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
```

https://www.raywenderlich.com/135655/whats-new-swift-3

Comment: Thanks! But how do I apply it in this line of code for example: {
                let size = text.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(view.frame.width - 26, 2000), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading.union(.UsesLineFragmentOrigin), context: nil).size}